iOS: How to stop playing previous notification custom sound using FCM
iOS: How to stop playing previous notification custom sound using FCM.
I've been working on FCM & React native recently and I faced this issue.
I use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Push a notification with custom sounds which is 24 seconds. (when a user is calling)

{
  "notification": {
    "title": "message 1",
    "body": "message 1",
  },
  "token": "token",
  "apns": {
    "headers": {
      "apns-priority": "10"
    },
    "payload": {
      "aps": {
        "sound": "customize_file",
      }
    }
  },
  "android": {
    "priority": "high",
    "notification": {
      "sound": "customize_file",
    }
  }
}


Push an another notification with no sound.  (when a user stops the call)

{
  "notification": {
    "title": "message 2",
    "body": "message 2",
  },
  "token": "token",
  "apns": {
    "headers": {
      "apns-priority": "10"
    },
  },
  "android": {
    "priority": "high",
    "notification": {
    }
  }
}


After the second notification, I want the sound to stop but it keeps ringing.

I tried apns-collapse-id but it doesn't seem working because message1 is already sent.
I want the sound to stop after the second notification.
